# my rocketMQ 2m-noslave can not consumer messages

Tags: rocketmq

I build a rocketmq serveice on my server,it is 2m-noslave cluster,it's can be send messages to rocketmq,but my consumer cannot receive message,somebody tell me where is wrong,thinks...this is my 
Consumer CLass code:

```
public class Consumer{

    public static final String CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME = "broker-b";
    public static final String CLUSTER_ADDR = "120.27.128.207:9876;120.27.146.42:9876";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE = "dzg_topic_001";

    private void consumerMessage() throws MQClientException {
        DefaultMQPushConsumer consumer = new DefaultMQPushConsumer(CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME);
        consumer.setNamesrvAddr(CLUSTER_ADDR);
        consumer.setConsumeFromWhere(ConsumeFromWhere.CONSUME_FROM_FIRST_OFFSET);
        consumer.setMessageModel(MessageModel.CLUSTERING);
        //设置批量消费个数
        consumer.subscribe(SUBSCRIBE, "*");

        consumer.registerMessageListener((List<MessageExt> msgList, ConsumeConcurrentlyContext context)->{
            MessageExt msg = msgList.get(0);
            System.out.println( "received new message:  topic===="+msg.getTopic()+"  tag==="+msg.getTags()+"  body=="+new String(msg.getBody()));
            return ConsumeConcurrentlyStatus.CONSUME_SUCCESS;
        });
        consumer.start();
        System.out.println("ConsumerStarted.");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Consumer().consumerMessage();
        } catch (MQClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

and my rocketmq server is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oCAH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

when I set property autoCreateTopicEnable and autoCreateSubscriptionGroup'svalue is true,the consumer is right,why set false the consumer is can not work?